# How to split string in Python to take only middle characters?

Tags: python, string, split, slice

I have string

```
['tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T11-59-06.json.gz']
```

I want to get only `59-06`

```
>>> f.split('_')
['tick', 'calculated', '2', '2020-05-27T11-59-06.json.gz']
>>> f.split('_')[3]
'2020-05-27T11-59-06.json.gz'

>>> f.split('_')[3].split('.')[0]
'2020-05-27T11-59-06'
```

What should be the next step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going in the right direction.
Contrary to other answers, I feel regex is a bit of an overkill, apart from being slower and harder to understand and maintain.

Once you have the string `x = '2020-05-27T11-59-06'`, you can do `x.split('-')` to get a list `lst = ['2020', '05', '27T11', '59', '06']`.
You can then access the last 2 elements of this list to get what you want easily: `lst[-1], lst[-2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `re` (regex).

```py
import re

f = "tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T11-59-06.json.gz"

res = re.search(r"T\d+\-([\d\-]+)\.json\.gz", f)

print(res.groups()[0])
```

output:
`59-06`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't know about using regular expressions, try to Google python string slicing. You had the right idea to split by '_', continue it to split by '.' then slice the string thus acquired for last 5 chars

```
f = 'tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T11-59-06.json.gz'
splitted = f.split('_')
print(splitted)

date = splitted[3].split('.')[0]
specialNum = date[-5:]
print(specialNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.rfind` this way:

```py
index = s.rfind('-')
s[index - 2:index + 3]
```

Or use a regexp this way:

```py
import re
re.search(r'.{5}(?=\.json)', s).group()
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses Positive lookahead and Positive lookbehind to assert that match occurs accurately.

```
import re

string = 'tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T11-59-06.json.gz'

re.search(r'(?<=T\d{2}-)\d{2}-\d{2}(?=\.json)', string).group()
```

Output:

```
59-06
```